# Disable Page Navigation using Shortcuts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The WPF `Frame` element ships with some preconfigured shortcuts for easy navigation. For example, I can use my 5-button mouse to navigate forwards/backwards. Is there an easy solution to disable these shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

```
Frame f;
f.CommandBindings.Clear()
```

Comment: I tried this, however, I doesn't prevent me from using my extra mouse buttons for navigation.